# When I try to access the site, I get this error: "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Tags: dns, cname, namecheap

We have been facing a problem since last Thursday. My website is inaccessible for half of the people who try to access it through the domain [www.mundovapor.com](http://www.mundovapor.com), and nobody has been able to figure out the issue.
I need help to understand what's going on and to resolve it.

The strangest thing is that some people can access the site normally, while others can't at all unless they use a VPN or a public DNS. However, this is not feasible, as we can't tell all our customers to use a VPN or a public DNS. I need help to understand the issue with the domain and resolve it.

For example: When I try to access the site, I get this error: "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS resolver should be configured to resolve the IP address. This article may help shed some light on this topic. https://zindagitech.com/how-to-configure-dns-server-in-linux-os-in-9-simple-steps/